# Change Python Versions to call two different modules

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlite, python-2.6

I have a simple program in which I am using two modules i.e. sqlite3 and twython. Now the sqlite3 is for python2.6 and twython is for 2.7. So if I change my shebang line to 2.6 then twyhton fails i.e.

```
python2.6 t_first.py
ImportError: No module named twython
```

And if I do following

```
python2.7 t_first.py
ImportError: No module named _sqlite3
```

Any solution. 
Also virtualenv is not a best solution here.

Comment: Did you try to modify `sys.path` (by using `sys.path.append`) to point to the location of the respective module which cannot be imported? I would try to use 2.7 and make `sys.path` point to the twython module. I haven't worked with twython but its github page states it to be compatible with Python 2.6+, so 2.7 should work.

Answer (score 1):

`sqlite3` is usually a builtin for python (in 2.6 and 2.7). I suggest that you install a non-broken version of python 2.7, and install twython into the site-packages for that. If you don't want to do that, install `twython` into the 2.6 site-packages.

Comment: I initially thought of that and did tried to install from ground up but as I dont have root access so many things were failing apart....

Comment: @LonelySoul You do not need root access to make a private install of python.

Comment: Thanks for the lead. I already had Python2.6 installed in which sqlite3 is working properly. However when I call the executable of Python2.6 and 2.7 through Shebang its not working. I found the executable through which python command and they are /usr/bin/python2.6 and /usr/local/bin/python2.7 . Any solution about why its still not working.

Comment: @LonelySoul It's still not working because you're not doing anything remotely like what I suggested, you're still doing the same thing you were originally doing.

Comment: Sorry for trouble. So you are suggesting to use only one version and install all module for that , right and not two different versions. Thoguh by curiosity if I do mention both python versions in shebang and then logically it should bring the executable for actions. Isn'it.

Comment: @LonelySoul You understand my suggestion. You do not understand how shebang works. You can only mention one executable - everything else is a parameter passed to the executable.

Comment: damn "shebang"  thanks for that hint. unfortunately I dont have any permission it seems . I am using the commands like ./configure --prefix=/usr/local for all imaginable changes but its denying permission every time.

Comment: @LonelySoul Install to a location you have permission to write to. Use `--help` to figure out how, or go ask over at the *nix SE.

Answer (score -1):

you could use exception handling to manage the import process. Something along the lines of:

```
try:
    import twython
except ImportError:
    import _sqlite3
```

This works if you assume that you need either one of the two present in any context. This would provide a preference to twython and fall back to _sqlite3 if twython is not available. It is an acceptable logical equivalent to:

```
if "twython exists" import twython else import _sqlite3
```

If you want to be more specific about the environments you could also do the following:

```
import sys
if sys.version_info == (2, 6):
    import _sqlite3
elif sys.version_info == (2, 7):
    import twython
```

Comment: How did it solves the different version problem. Seems to be more like error handling and hesitate to put into production.

Comment: @LonelySoul The original idea gave you a option for an if/then type of import based on which modules are present. I updated the answer with something that is more detailed around python versions and may be a better fit for what you are looking for. Thoughts?

Comment: The problem is to bring both versions in action through shebang line.